# Reflection can't get the actual parameter type of a method that overrides from a generic-typed interface?

Tags: java, reflection

**EDIT: Sorry the example I provide below doesn't reproduce the problem... I'm trying to find the right way to reproduce it. Before that, you may just ignore my question...**

Usually we grab the parameter type of a method like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = method.getParameterTypes()[0]
```

I have never thought twice about it before, but recently I bumped into an issue that I always got `class java.lang.Object` when doing that. After an inspection, I found out the case can be described like this:

```
/** A parameterized interface */
public interface IService<T> {

    Result create(T obj);
}

/** An implementation */
public class CarService implements IService<Car> {

    public Result create(Car car) { ... }
}
```

And then when I use the way above to get the class of the parameter `car`, it turns out to be a `class java.lang.Object`:

```
Method methods = CarService.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    Class<?>[] types = method.getParameterTypes();
    // when the loop meets "create" here ...
}
```

I guess I have totally forgot something very fundamental about type erase? But now I really need get the actual parameter type in this case, if it's possible...

Comment: try `method.getGenericParameterTypes()` instead of `method.getParameterTypes()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is type erasure being annoying. It's worth looking at what you get in bytecode here:

```
class Car {}
interface IService<T> {
    void create(T obj);
}

class CarService implements IService<Car> {
    public void create(Car car) {}
}
```

Then:

```
$ javac Test.java # Contains all the above...
$ javap -c CarService

Compiled from "Test.java"
class CarService implements IService<Car> {
  CarService();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void create(Car);
    Code:
       0: return

  public void create(java.lang.Object);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #2                  // class Car
       5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method create:(LCar;)V
       8: return
}
```

And those are *also* shown when you use reflection:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method[] methods = CarService.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
            for (Class<?> type : method.getParameterTypes()) {
                System.out.printf("- %s%n", type.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
create
- Car
create
- java.lang.Object
```

How you use this will depend on exactly what you're trying to achieve, but hopefully the awareness that there are multiple methods in the bytecode will help...

Comment: THANK YOU! Two method with the same name... That makes me thought the example I provide in the question doesn't reproduce the problem in the first place. It takes me a simple "if" to workaround this.